# ¿Cómo leer varios archivos Excel de una carpeta, mediante un bucle?

Tags: r

Buen día les agradecería su ayuda:

Tengo varios archivos ".xlsx" en una carpeta y lo quisiera de forma iterativa,
para luego juntarlos todos en un solo.

```
datos01 <-read_excel("ATENCION DIARIA EMG 01.09.2019.xlsx", skip=5)
datos01 <-datos01[-(11:44),-c(1,3,16,17,18,19,20)]
fecha   <-as.Date(rep("2019-09-01",10))
datos01 <-cbind(datos01, fecha)

datos02 <- read_excel("ATENCION DIARIA EMG 02.09.2019.xlsx", skip=5)
datos02 <-datos02[-(11:44),-c(1,3,16,17,18,19,20)]
fecha   <-as.Date(rep("2019-09-02",10))
datos02 <-cbind(datos02, fecha)

datos03 <- read_excel("ATENCION DIARIA EMG 03.09.2019.xlsx", skip=5)
datos03 <-datos03[-(11:44),-c(1,3,16,17,18,19,20)]
fecha   <-as.Date(rep("2019-09-03",10))
datos03 <-cbind(datos03, fecha)

datos04 <- read_excel("ATENCION DIARIA EMG 04.09.2019.xlsx", skip=5)
datos04 <-datos04[-(11:44),-c(1,3,16,17,18,19,20)]
fecha   <-as.Date(rep("2019-09-04",10))
datos04 <-cbind(datos04, fecha)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes iterar sobre la lista de archivos `xlsx` que te retorna `list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')`, pero obviamente no podrás especificar variables individuales para cada archivo, sino que deberías administrar todas las bases de dato en una única lista:

```
datos <- list()    
i <- 1
for (file in list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')) {

  datos[[i]] <- read_excel(file, skip=5)
  datos[[i]] <- datos[[i]][-(11:44),-c(1,3,16,17,18,19,20)]
  fecha <- as.Date(rep("2019-09-01",10)) + (i - 1)
  datos[[i]] <-cbind(datos[[i]], fecha)

  i <- i + 1
}
```

Comentarios:

- `datos` será nuestra lista con cada `data.frame`, podemos luego acceder a cada uno de ellos por índice, por ejemplo al cuarto `datos[[4]]`
- `as.Date(rep("2019-09-01",10)) + (i - 1)` construye un vector de fechas para cada uno de los días a mendida que se incrementa `i`