# ¿Cómo unir varios archivos csv de datos con un for en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una serie de información que requiero unir en una sola base. He intentado lo siguiente, pero al final del resultado no me une los archivos.

```
## PathProject
Pathproject = "E:/Tesis2/precipitacion_faltante";
# 
# ## List Folders####Estaciones ideam############ 
Namefiles = list.files(Pathproject, recursive = FALSE)

###########union de archivos descargados########
datos <- data.table()

for (i in length(Namefiles)) {
    tmp   <- data.table()
    tmp   <- read.table((file.path(Pathproject, Namefiles[i])), sep =",", header = TRUE)
    #data  <- as.data.table(fread(file.path(Pathproject, Namefiles[i])), sep =",", header=TRUE)
    datos <- rbind(datos, tmp)
}
```

El resultado es q datos es igual al ultimo tmp. ¿Que me falta?

Comment: Bienvenido Alberto! Hay algunas preguntas/respuestas sobre este tema. Por ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304646/c%c3%b3mo-trabajar-con-m%c3%baltiples-dataframes-de-forma-iterativa/304651#304651 hay una solución con `lapply`, en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302736/c%c3%b3mo-leer-varios-archivos-excel-de-una-carpeta-mediante-un-bucle hay una usando bucles, si lo prefieres.

Comment: En este caso creo que lo mejor es usar `lapply` o algún funcional por el estilo, sobre todo porque te ahorras el paso de armar manualmente el  output del bucle y se controla mejor el problema de los entornos. Al respecto, si vas a trabajar con un bucle lo ideal sería envolverlo en una función para aislarlo del entorno global: de ese modo que asegurás que no cambie nada y que funcione aisladamente, es decir, que no requiera que esté definida una estructura de datos en otra parte del script (que en un par de meses no vas a recordar cuál es!). Además suelen ser más rápidos.

Comment: Sobre "más rápidos": `lapply` es un bucle implícito, pero un bucle programado con buenas prácticas. No es intrínsecamente más rápido que un bucle bien hecho, pero suele ser mucho más rápido que un bucle armado a las apuradas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres unir son archivos .csv.

Veo que haces uso de la librería data.table, por lo que te doy una solución con rbindlist que pertenece también a la librería data.table.
Para unir distintas tablas con rbindlist, deben estar en una lista.

```
library(data.table)

## PathProject
Pathproject = "E:/Tesis2/precipitacion_faltante"

## files
Namefiles = list.files(Pathproject, full.names = TRUE)

## unión de archivos descargados
tmp <- list() 
for (i in 1:length(Namefiles)) tmp[[i]] <- fread(Namefiles[i])
datos <- rbindlist(tmp)
```